# Is the [Run] section processed before the CurStepChanged event for the ssPostInstall step is fired?

Tags: inno-setup

In my code I'm using the `[Run]` section as well as the `CurStepChanged` event handler doing some stuff when the `ssPostInstall` occurs. In pseudo script something like this:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\FileToRun.exe"; Parameters: "/x"

[Code]
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then 
  begin
    // do some stuff
  end;
end;
```

My question is, which one is processed as first. Is the `[Run]` section processed before the `CurStepChanged` event for the `ssPostInstall` step is fired?

From what I've observed it seems that the `[Run]` section is processed as first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is true. The [`[Run]`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection) section entries are processed before the [`CurStepChanged`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurStepChanged) event for the [`ssPostInstall`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=TSetupStep) step is fired. It can be read in the following [`piece of code`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/Projects/Main.pas#L3883) (comments are mine):

```
ProcessRunEntries; // <- this processes the [Run] section entries

if RmDoRestart and
   (InitRestartApplications or
    ((shRestartApplications in SetupHeader.Options) and not InitNoRestartApplications)) then
  RestartApplications;

SetStep(ssPostInstall, True); // <- and this triggers the CurStepChanged event
```

Comment: Thanks! @TLama. Is it possible to run a batch file(as of now i am using[RUN]) in CurStepChanged event?

Comment: You're welcome! To your question; yes, check out the [`Exec`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_exec) function.