How to keep registry even though uninsdeletekey was specified in Inno Setup
Annoyingly I specified the uninsdeletekey flag in my installer:
Root: "HKA"; Subkey: "Software\Company\Application"; Flags: uninsdeletekey

Similar questions:

How to keep registry keys after uninstall with Inno Setup
Registry Inno Setup uninsdeletekey but not on upgrade

The second question is more related to my issue. But I am not in a position to modify any uninstaller, as proposed in the answer.
It has been like this for 20 years! But I have now created two installers for the same program. One for 32/64 respectively and during installer they remove the old application.
On the upside,no user data is lost. On the down down, all data in registry is lost. I had a look at the command line switches for the uninstaller and there seems to be nothing to prevent this happening.
At the moment the only solution I can think of is:

Run bespoke tool to extract the key using original user account.
Uninstall old application.
Install new application.
Run bespoke too to import the key back in using the original user account.

Am I reinventing the wheel here? I am trying to see if there is an existing elegant solution to this problem.
If I didn’t do that all the settings would still be there.

I stumbled on this question:

How to export a registry in c#

In one of the answers it says about using reg.exe to export the key. So my updated idea now is:

Run reg.exe with original user account if possible to create the file.
Uninstall
Install
When app starts look for presence of this file if exists use reg.exe to import it.

Either that or write my own tool to do the same.

I confirm that step one works:
ExecAsOriginalUser(ExpandConstant('{sys}\reg.exe'), \
    'export "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Company\Application" "d:\test.txt"', \
    '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ExportRegResult);
    Log(SysErrorMessage(ExportRegResult));

But I hardcoded it with a d:\test.txt. I can't find out how to get a temporary file name, for us to copy into the user data folder at the end of the installation.

Imo, that's the best solution (or don't run the old uninstaller)

To get a path to a temporary folder, to temporarily store the  registry, use {tmp} constant:
ExpandConstant('{tmp}\backup.reg')


Additionally, the ExecAsOriginalUser and HKEY_CURRENT_USER do not match with the HKA Registry entry in your old (un)installer.
Imo you should:

Use Exec – to run the reg with the same privileges and under the same account with which your old (un)installer operates.
Use HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE when IsAdminInstallMode is true – to match HKA behaviour.


For some examples of reg.exe error handling from Inno Setup, see:
Creating registry key for logged in user (not admin user) in Inno Setup

Thank you. I should clarify … HKA is what I am using in my new installers. The old one actually used HKLM.

Ok, in that case, you definitely cannot use ExecAsOriginalUser because it would run reg without administrator privileges – would work when exporting you are doing now, but not when importing.

I see one of your answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70235152/2287576 so it looks like I can just add a run entry. Make the path string global. And add a check function to return true if the file exists.

Yes you can do that. Though I personally would prefer using the same API (Exec) for the import as for the export (as you cannot export using the Run, unless you run the uninstaller the same way – what I assume you do not)

I use [PrepareToInstall] to test for existence of old app, use Exec to export reg and then Exec to uninstall. Then in [Run] section the first item is to import with Exec if file exists. Works well.  I don’t know how to do the latter via the [Code] section instead.
Andrew Truckle
23 mins ago

This one helps. CurStepChanged and ssPostInstall. Call Exec there. https://stackoverflow.com/q/29841276/2287576  But Run is called before ssPostInstall. So that is not good because I want to import the key before user potentially runs the program, which is an option they can tick.

The postinstall (=those with checkbox) [Run] entries are run only after CurStepChanged(ssPostInstall).

Check the accepted answer there which even shows the Inno source code snippet: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29842241/2287576 unless it has changed. Or if that answer is inaccurate it needs updating.

@AndrewTruckle Again, postinstall entries (those with checkbox) are processed asynchronously after ssPostInstall. The non-postinstall are indeed processed synchronously before. The TLama's answer is for a question on a non-postinstall entry.

Alright, I got it to work. But, now that I am doing itself, is there any built-in mechanism for letting the user know it did not work? Ie: How would [Run] handle things and inform a failure? Shall we tidy these comments and I do a new question about that?

What failure? All that Run reports to the user is when it cannot run the program at all. What is unlikely with reg. It does not handle internal program errors  anyhow. With Exec, you can test it return value (reporting if the program cannot be run) and the programs' exit code (possibly reporting internal program errors - in this case like non existing registry key, etc). See for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/28824766/850848 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/9621099/850848 and many many others.
